# Changing file permissions to 777 breaks website

Tags: magento2, theme, file-permissions

I am trying to install a theme to a magento site, but running `setup:upgrade` after the files are transferred breaks all css and javascript. I read that the file permissions may be an issue, so after running `chmod -R 777 .`  the whole site breaks, and returns a 500 Internal Server Error. What can I do to install this theme without breaking the site, and if it is a permissions problem how do you change the file permissions without breaking the website?

Comment: Do you find anything in server log?

Comment: Add the `error_reporting( E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors',1);` in top of your `index.php` file after php tag `<?php` to get actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the permission so it matches the permissions your webserver is running under. I wouldn't recommend using 777 permissions as this allows global write permissions. In a shared hosting environment i prefer to use :

```
chown -R webserveruser:webservergroup ./ PATH
```

Replace webserveruser etc.. with the actual user/group. you can check this by doing ls -la

Edited:

Don't use chmod 777, the reason you get this error is the user you are logged in as when you run setup:upgrade has root(or higher permissions) than the user your webserver/php is running under. Any files/folders created with the setup script (eg: var/generation) will be owned by root and so is not accessible by the webserver/php when you reload the page in your browser.

The fix for this ***isn't*** to grant permission to ***every*** user on your server but only grant permission to the user who ***actually*** needs access.

The next time you run setup:upgrade consider doing a

```
su webserveruser
```

first as this will ensure the files modified are still accessible by the webserver.

Comment: The server we have is Siteground Cloud hosting, would that still apply as it is not a shared hosting environment?

Comment: Yes i have found the above works the best

Comment: chmod 777 is bad, have a read of this https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777